# Ensure only one setTimeout runs (is active) at a time?

Tags: javascript, recursion, global-variables, settimeout, function-call

The recursive `setTimeout` function getRandomProducts is called `onload` in the html body tag, and so is constantly iterating.
The function setCategoryTree is being called `onclick` from the links in a nested ul of a navigation-bar. *This function then passes the variable mainCategory to getRandomProducts, in which the variable is declared globally to maintain its' initialization.*
...So, what I am trying to do is reset the getRandomProducts function when a link is clicked in the navigation-bar, and pass the category name from the link that was clicked. However, `clearTimeout` does not seem to be working and so the iterations occur a lot more frequently as there are then **multiple** recursive loops executing simultaneously.
And not only that, but my global variables are not storing data from setCategoryTree as intended (basically I am trying to use the global variable similarly to a static-variable). I have discerned all of this behavior with the `window.alert` that is commented out.
Here is the relevant Javascript code:

```
var mainCategory = ""; // initialized from setCategoryTree
var category = mainCategory;

function getRandomProducts(category)
{
    //window.alert(category);
    if(typeof category == "undefined")
        category = "all";
    else
        clearTimeout(t);

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var products = document.getElementById("products");

    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if( (req.readyState == 4) && (req.status == 200) )
        {
            var result = req.responseText;
            products.innerHTML = result;
        }
    }
    req.open("GET", "default.php?category=" + category, true);
    req.send(null);

    var t = setTimeout("getRandomProducts()", 1000);
}

function setCategoryTree(link)
{
    var categoryTree = document.getElementById("categoryTree");

    /* climbing the DOM-tree to get the category name (innerHTML of highest "a" tag) */
        mainCategory = link.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;

    var subcategory = link.innerHTML;

    categoryTree.innerHTML = "--&nbsp;" + mainCategory + "&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;" + subcategory;

    getRandomProducts(mainCategory);
}
```

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: (`t` is *always* undefined at `clearTimeout`.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick replies everybody. I have implemented all of your suggestions, and that corrected the `setTimeout/clearTimeout` problem... but when uncommenting the `window.alert` there are some unusual positive and negative integers appearing instead of the intended string! Any ideas?

Comment: your response is very vague. Not sure what the problem is. If my answer helped you, could you also please mark that one as best. With any further problems, please raise a new question.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out -- I was incorrectly passing a global variable as an argument, with some weird unexpected errors. Thanks for help everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the variable `t` within the function. The next time this function gets called the var `t` will not be available for you.

Therefore, Set the variable above the function (not in it)

```
var randomProductsTimeout = false;

function getRandomProducts(category){

    randomProductsTimeout = setTimeout()[..]
```