# ajax $.get() - requesting twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this js code loads more content from server if you reach the bottom part of the page:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == getDocHeight()) {
    var next_pagenumber = parseInt($('#next_pagenumber').val());
    var num_pages = parseInt($('#num_pages').val());

    if(next_pagenumber <= num_pages){
      $.get("?page_number=" + (next_pagenumber).toString(), function(data) {
         if(data != "nomore"){
             setTimeout(
                 function(){
                      $('#next_pagenumber').val(next_pagenumber+1);
                      $('#morenews').append(data);
                 }, 500);
        }else{
             $('#loadmore').hide();
        }
      });

   }else{
      console.log('no more pages to load');
        }
   }
```

but, if you  scroll down really fast twice, 2 requests with the same `GET` are being sent.

how can I make the code wait until the response of the former requests is here?

Comment: You may want to look into a `debounce` function.

Comment: Have one boolean - set it to true when ajax starts and in the success, make it false. This would work.

Comment: @JamieDixon sounds good, but cannot find appropriate example for my case :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ensure only one setTimeout runs (is active) at a time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084794/ensure-only-one-settimeout-runs-is-active-at-a-time)

Comment: Why are you using a timeout in `$.get()` success callback? Regarding debouncing event, see e.g: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the test case Bharath was speaking of. Set a boolean variable to true, and set it to false after the success.

I am checking of the boolean value is true in the IF statement that checks the page numbers.

```
var ajaxTest = true;
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == getDocHeight()) {
    var next_pagenumber = parseInt($('#next_pagenumber').val());
    var num_pages = parseInt($('#num_pages').val());

    if(next_pagenumber <= num_pages && ajaxTest == true){
      $.get("?page_number=" + (next_pagenumber).toString(), function(data) {
         ajaxTest = false; 
         if(data != "nomore"){
              setTimeout(
                 function(){
                      $('#next_pagenumber').val(next_pagenumber+1);
                      $('#morenews').append(data);
                 }, 500);
        }else{
             $('#loadmore').hide();
        }
      });

   }else{
      console.log('no more pages to load');
        }
}
```

Also, here is a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5eh2b7fb/1/

Comment: you setting ``var ajaxTest = true;`` in every scroll event, does the variable have not to be global?

Comment: @doniyor You should really debounce event, that's usually the best way to avoid behaviour as you are facing

Comment: I agree, however, I was just showing an example of a comment above. This may not be the cleanest way, but it is a way. :)

Comment: @A.Wolff your right. i will take a look at debouncing. i always wanted to try it

Comment: @MikeLegacy ya, an other way even you should reset global variable in success callback i guess. Maybe OP wants some kind of infinite scrolling

Comment: @MikeLegacy thanks dude, i did like ``way_is_open = true;`` so it is REALLY global and reset in every success scope.